# How to break syslog into smaller files without losing data

Tags: shell-script, files, file-copy, syslog

Here we try to break `syslog` file into smaller chunks. For that we use following script.

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)
 
cp /path/to/sys.log /path/to/chuck/file.log
cat /dev/null > /path/to/sys.log

cp /path/to/chuck/file.log /path/to/chuck/file_"$date".log
cat /dev/null > /path/to/chuck/file.log
```

This script runs in every 5mins and break the `syslog` into a smaller log, which we use to further processing.
Issue is that there are some records missing in original `syslog` and chunked file. Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Here chunked file is around ~2GB. `syslog` is continuously growing.

Comment: Have you considered using `logrotate` and force a rotate every five minutes? That would create your chunked files. However, it would also create a new primary log file on each run - something that might not work well with your workflow.

Comment: How do you know records a missing? And what do you mean "in the original `syslog`"? Are they missing even before the copy / truncate the file? Also, why do you make the copy twice? Why don't you copy the file directly to the file with the date?

Comment: @aviro No, they are not missing in the original file. Yes, we tried just directly copying to the destination file. Still the same result.

Comment: If they are not missing in the original file, how are they missing after the copy? After the copy, everything in the original file should also be in the new file. Do you have an example? Something that wasn't missing in the original file, but then after copy it is suddenly missing? And I'll repeat my first question: How do you know a certain record is missing?

Comment: Between the `cp` and the `cat` more data can be added to the original file. This data will be lost.

Comment: @meuh Yes, thats the issue we are having.

Answer (score 3):

**Caveat:** this did not work perfectly for me on version 8.2002 with some small max sizes and module `imfile` for input. Some data was lost in log files, but the documentation in general warns that small buffer sizes are not supported.

---

If you are using rsyslog, it provides a built-in mechanism to rotate log
files when they exceed a certain size. You simply create a
[channel](https://rsyslog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/output_channels.html),
specifying the filename, max size, and name of a script to run when the
size is exceeded. Then
[use](https://rsyslog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/log_rotation_fix_size.html)
the channel name instead of the filename in a filter.

For example, to run script `/home/me/rotatescript` when over 50Mibytes have
been written to file `/var/log/mylog`, create the channel named, say, `mylogrotatechan`:

```
$outchannel mylogrotatechan,/var/log/mylog,52428800,/home/me/rotatescript
```

and replace `*.* /var/log/mylog` by

```
*.* :omfile:$mylogrotatechan
```

There is also a test script in the latest sources (from Jan 2023) which
uses this undocumented RainerScript syntax:

```
action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/mylog" rotation.sizeLimit="52428800"
       rotation.sizeLimitCommand="/home/me/rotatescript")
```

A typical script might be

```bash
#!/bin/bash
mv /var/log/mylog /var/log/mylog.$(date +%Y%m%d.%H%M%S)
```

Comment: Here one of our main concern is that we need this log file to be certain 5mins. If we break by size, time gap may vary,

Answer (score 3):

I'd use perl's [File::Tail](https://metacpan.org/release/File-Tail) for this (I use it for almost anything which needs to monitor - i.e. continuosly tail - a log file).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

# File::Tail need to be installed from a distro package e.g. 'apt
# install libfile-tail-perl' on debian, ubuntu, mint etc or from
# CPAN https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Tail
# BTW, File::Tail has several useful options, run `man File::Tail`
# for details.
use File::Tail;

# These two need to be installed from a distro package e.g. 'apt
# install libtimedate-perl' on debian, ubuntu, mint etc or from
# CPAN https://metacpan.org/release/TimeDate
use Date::Parse;
use Date::Format;

# These two modules are included with perl
use File::Basename;
use Scalar::Util qw(openhandle);

use strict;

# $logfile is hard-coded here, but you can get it from the command line
# e.g. with something as simple as `my $logfile = shift` or use one of
# the command-line option processing modules like Getopt::Std or
# Getopt::Long
my $logfile = '/var/log/syslog';

# the output dir is hard-coded here to `chunk/` in the current dir.
# set it to whatever you want, or get it from the command line.
my $basename = './chunk/' . basename($logfile);

# open a handle to the log file.  File::Tail will automatically
# re-open the log file if it gets rotated and re-created.
my $logref=tie(*LOG,"File::Tail", (name => $logfile, tail => -1));

my ($d, $t, $t2, $outfile, $chunk);

while(<LOG>) {
  # Example of handling two different common rsyslog logfile date
  # formats.  Adjust the regex(es) to suit YOUR log file.
  if (/^([[:alpha:]]{3} \d+ \d\d:\d\d):/i) {
    # Jul 25 00:00:02 ....
    $d = $1;
  } elsif (/^(\d{4}[ T]\d\d:\d\d):/) {
    # 2023-07-25T00:00:01.737457+10:00 ....
    $d = $1;
  } else {
    die "Couldn't find a known date format in:\n$_";
  };
  $t = str2time($d);

  if ($t - $t2 >= 300) {
    close($chunk) if openhandle($chunk);
    # Alternatively, you could run your chunk processing
    # program from here:
    # (this is really basic & untested but it should work...but
    # there are better ways of handling child processes.)
    # if (openhandle($chunk)) {
    #   close($chunk);
    #
    #   $SIG{CHLD} = "IGNORE";
    #   fork;
    #   exec("myprogram", $outfile) or
    #     warn "Couldn't exec 'myprogram $outfile'\n";
    # };


    $t2 = $t;
    $d = time2str("%Y%m%d_%H%M", $t);
    $outfile = "${basename}_$d";

    # Ignore output files that already exist, so that we can
    # just re-run this script if it gets killed for some reason.
    if (! -e $outfile) {
      print "opening new output file $outfile\n";
      open($chunk, ">", $outfile) or
        die "couldn't open $outfile for write: $!\n";
    }
  };

  print $chunk $_ if openhandle($chunk);
}
```

Save it as, e.g., `split-log-5min.pl` or similar, make it executable with `chmod +x split-log-5min.pl` and run it.  It will keep running and processing data from the log file until it is killed (e.g. with Ctrl-C or with `kill`), or until there's an error trying to open an output file for write..

I ran this on an extract from my /var/log/syslog and ended up with a `./chunk` directory containing lots of 5 minute chunks:

```
$ ls chunk/
syslog_20230725_0000  syslog_20230725_0519  syslog_20230725_1037
syslog_20230725_0007  syslog_20230725_0525  syslog_20230725_1043
syslog_20230725_0013  syslog_20230725_0531  syslog_20230725_1049
syslog_20230725_0019  syslog_20230725_0537  syslog_20230725_1055
[...many more deleted]
syslog_20230725_0455  syslog_20230725_1013  syslog_20230725_1531
syslog_20230725_0501  syslog_20230725_1019  syslog_20230725_1537
syslog_20230725_0507  syslog_20230725_1025
syslog_20230725_0513  syslog_20230725_1031
```

---

BTW, depending on what, exactly, you're doing with the five-minute chunks, you may be able to process them in this script without needing to copy the chunks to separate files.  e.g. instead of writing to a file, append each line to an array and then process & clear the array every five minutes.